# Simpliest way of organizing divs, is this it?

Tags: css, html, center

I need my #header centered..

I am wondering if I have gone about this all wrong.. I want the code to be the simplest as possible... Should I go about making three div like tables to get the left middle right adjusting more fluidly..

http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/24/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/24/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I see no problem with the way your divs are organized. Please be more specific.

Comment: I need the #header center inline with #registration

Answer (score 3):

You just needed some basic fundamental knowledge of how and when to use display:block, inline, and inline-block. As well as floats

I centered your header. But you have to do your sizes and beautification yourself.

```
#header {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63096695/header.png) no-repeat;
    width:240px;
    height:100px;
    margin:20px auto;
    display:block;
}
```

See [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/kDrJL/31/)

1. Now, as far as whether this is the best way to place your divs. Not necessarily bad, but I would consider a more semantic structure. So instead of div="header" consider `<header>` instead as well as `<nav><section><aside><footer><address>` etc

Comment: the #registration fell out of line with #header though,

Comment: you wanted the header centered. The register and header are two different elements. If you want the register to be part of the header, then you must consider that the header will be splitting the house with two sections. In this case it is better to make a 100% parent and divide the house among its children equally. I made some changes to your fiddle

Comment: lotusms, I like your suggestion about `<header>` etc, but that requires `<!DOCTYPE html>` (HTML5) & will not work in IE8 without something like html5shiv

Comment: You are correct. But is our job to pave the road for future technology by implementing new technology while still being able to access the old. It's always been a challenge for any developer to merge both technologies. But it is what it is, right :)

Answer (score 1):

Extend the width of `#header` to `420px` or more. Move `#register` inside `#header`. Remove `display: inline-block` style from `#header`.

http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/30/